# Prime Factorization of a Positive Integer with Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, prime-factoring

I am currently trying to incorporate the Stream API of Java 8 into my everyday Java toolbox. I am trying to use Streams to find the prime factors of a positive integer, and then store each of the factors in an array(or `ArrayList`) with their multiplicity in a parallel array. Alternatively, I'm trying to create a Stream of say... `FactorWithMultiplicity` objects, or even a `Map` with the factor as the key and the multiplicity as the value. It would be nice if the factors were sorted in ascending order, and if it could even handle very large numbers (such as, dare I say, `Long.MAX_VALUE`).

Currently, my code looks like this, but, as I am a beginner with Streams, I am sure there is a faster or better suited way to accomplish this task. Please use Streams to create your solution, although if you know that some non-Stream solution is faster, feel free to point me to that code also.

```
int num = getPositiveInt();
ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> multiplicities = new ArrayList<>();
boolean isPrime = IntStream.rangeClosed(2, num / 2)
    .reduce(num, (int temp, int factor) -> {
        int count = 0;
        while (temp % factor == 0) {
            temp /= factor;
            count++;
        }
        if (count > 0) {
            factors.add(factor);
            multiplicities.add(count);
        }
        return temp;
    }) > 1;
```

Comment: I feel that you are using streams are a weird way. This is because you are using it to execute a lambda to manipulate external variables, whereas normally the purpose of a stream is to map or filter the numbers in the stream itself.

Comment: @Nayuki You're right. I think it would be much better if the lambda mapped to a Stream that contains the prime factors and their multiplicities.

Comment: I think that the real solution is not to use streams for this problem at all.

Comment: @StephenC Please explain. I think my solution did it perfectly well, don't you? At minimum I'm just using Streams here as a foreach loop, but reduce does even more than that.

Comment: An OO representation of a prime factor might be a small object combining factor and multiplicity.

Comment: @laune That would be perfect! I added that as an option for a solution in the question.

Comment: @Nayuki I've now created a semi-solution that does those things. You might like to take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you specifically want a streams-based solution, you can have a method that recursively factors a number:

```
IntStream factors(int num) {
    return IntStream.range(2, num)
        .filter(x -> num % x == 0)
        .mapToObj(x -> IntStream.concat(IntStream.of(x), factors(num / x)))
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(IntStream.of(num));
}
```

Then you can use the following code to make your two lists:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> f2m = factors(2, num).boxed()
        .collect(toMap(f -> f, f -> 1, Integer::sum));  // or groupingBy with summingInt(f->1), whichever you prefer

List<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>(f2m.keySet());
List<Integer> multiplicities = factors.stream().map(f2m::get).collect(toList());
```

If you want to get a bit more performance out of it, you can pass last found factor to `factors` method and use that instead of `2`.

If you want to factor longs, here's a version with a few performance improvements:

```
static LongStream factors(long lastFactor, long num) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(lastFactor, (long) Math.sqrt(num))
            .filter(x -> num % x == 0)
            .mapToObj(x -> LongStream.concat(LongStream.of(x), factors(x, num / x)))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(LongStream.of(num));
}
```

If you want the result to be in sorted order, you can use

```
SortedMap<Long, Integer> f2m = factors(2, num).boxed()
         .collect(toMap(f -> f, f -> 1, Integer::sum, TreeMap::new));
```

Or, alternatively, keep the `Map` as it was and use

```
List<Long> factors = f2m.keySet().stream().sorted().collect(toList());
```

Comment: If you make 3 changes to this code, it will be the best! (For a Stream, otherwise **[this solution](https://ideone.com/pdshk6#stdin)** is basically unbeatable) First, switch everything over to `Long` so that much bigger numbers can be used (because this solution can eat them for breakfast). Second, change the `factors` method to use `.rangeClosed(2, (long) Math.sqrt(num))` (HUGE speed boost). Third, add `.sorted()` after the `.orElse` (because that would be super helpful and doesn't even make a dent in speed).

Comment: I used `int` because that's what the question used.  Skipped various performance optimizations for the same reason -- even large `int`s get factored very fast.  I will add a `long` version to the answer.  Adding `sorted()` before `boxed()` is pointless since `toMap` will not preserve the order anyway.  If you want the result to be sorted, you can use `toMap` with `TreeMap::new` or else sort the output of `keySet()`.

Comment: Sounds good, in that case just add the performance optimizations to the `long` version. Also, I found that wrapping `f2m` with `new TreeMap<>()` was also an easy solution for sorting.

Comment: It's not necessary to make a `Map` and then wrap with `TreeMap`.  You can make the `TreeMap` directly with the `toMap` collector.  See the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

Another variant which would be useful if you want to call `factorsOf` repeatedly. (I stole the basic idea of the sieve somewhere, fixed it.)

The idea here is to use the primes as the stream, filtering the factors and determine their multiplicity to create the FactorTimes objects establishing the result.

```
public class PrimeFactors  {
  private final int limit = 1_000_000;
  private BitSet sieve = new BitSet( limit+1 );
  public PrimeFactors(){
    sieve.set( 2, limit );
    long count = sieve.stream()
    .peek( x -> { if( (long)x*x < limit )
                    for( int i = x*x; i <= limit; i += x )
                      sieve.clear( i );
                })
    .count();
  }
  public FactorTimes[] factorsOf( int num ){
    FactorTimes[] fts = sieve.stream()
    .limit( num/2 )
    .filter( x -> num % x == 0 ) 
    .mapToObj( x -> { int n = 1;
                      int k = num/x;
                      while( k % x == 0 ){ k /= x; n++; }
                      return new  FactorTimes( x, n );
                    } )
    .toArray( FactorTimes[]::new );
    return fts;
  }
  public static void main( String[] args ){
    PrimeFactors pf = new PrimeFactors();
    for( FactorTimes ft: pf.factorsOf( 4504500 ) ){
      System.out.println( ft );
    }
  }
}

class FactorTimes {
  private int factor, multiplicity;
  public FactorTimes(int f, int m) {
    factor = f; multiplicity = m;
  }
  public int getFactor() { return factor; }
  public int getMultiplicity() { return multiplicity; }
  public String toString(){
    return multiplicity > 1 ? factor + "(" + multiplicity + ")"
                            : Integer.toString( factor ); }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generate prime factors you need to keep track of several states. Therefore `Streams` are not well suited for this task.

What you can do is to provide an own `Spliterator` to create an `IntStream`. Now you're able to generate an array or the grouping operations:

```
public static IntStream primeFactors(int n) {
  int characteristics = Spliterator.ORDERED | Spliterator.SORTED | Spliterator.IMMUTABLE | Spliterator.NONNULL;
  Spliterator.OfInt spliterator = new Spliterators.AbstractIntSpliterator(Long.MAX_VALUE, characteristics) {
    int val = n;
    int div = 2;

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(IntConsumer action) {
      while (div <= val) {
        if (val % div == 0) {
          action.accept(div);
          val /= div;
          return true;
        }
        div += div == 2 ? 1 : 2;
      }
      return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super Integer> getComparator() {
      return null;
    }
  };
  return StreamSupport.intStream(spliterator, false);
}
```

And call something like this:

```
int n = 40500;
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primeFactors(n).toArray()));
System.out.println(primeFactors(n).boxed().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.summingInt(i -> 1)))
);
```

You should get your desired results:

```
[2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5]
{2=2, 3=4, 5=3}
```

Answer (score 0):

When factoring integers, the most profitable optimisation is to try divisors until the square root of the number (inclusively, ex.: try factoring 49).  Also, after checking for 2, you can check afterwards with only odd numbers.

```
int num = getPositiveInt();
ArrayList<Integer> factors = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<Integer> multiplicities = new ArrayList<>();
int factor = 2;
int f_delta = 1;  // to increase by +1 only once (2 to 3) 
while ((factor*factor)<=num) {
  int count = 0;
  while (num % factor == 0) {
    num /= factor;
    count++;
  }  
  if (count > 0) {
    factors.add(factor);
    multiplicities.add(count);
  }
  factor += f_delta;
  f_delta = 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for that advice! It's not using Streams though, so it's not really teaching what I intended this question to teach. There's already plenty of questions for how to do this without a Stream.

Answer (score 0):

After investigating thoroughly, I've found that this is an overwhelming improvement in speed compared to what I posted in the question. The only faster one is the one posted by **@Misha** after changing their `factors` function to use `.rangeClosed(prevFactor, Math.sqrt(num))` instead. However, **[this other solution](https://ideone.com/pdshk6)** is the fastest solution... period... but doesn't use Streams.

```
public static Map<Long, Integer> factorize(long num) { //NOW USING LONG
    Map<Long, Integer> factors = new LinkedHashMap<>(); //NOW USING MAP
    long lastRemainder = LongStream.rangeClosed(2, (long) Math.sqrt(num)) //NOW USING SQRT
            .filter(x -> (x== 2||x%2>0)&&(x==3||x%3>0)&&(x==5||x%5>0)) //ADDED THIS
            .reduce(num, (temp, factor) -> {
                if (factor <= temp / factor) { //ADDED THIS
                    int count = 0;
                    while (temp % factor == 0) {
                        temp /= factor;
                        count++;
                    }
                    if (count > 0)
                        factors.put(factor, count);
                }
                return temp;
            });
    if (lastRemainder != num && lastRemainder > 1) //ADDED THIS
        factors.put(lastRemainder, 1);
    return factors;
}
```